# RecyclerView ItemDecoration: Spacing AND Divider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Below is how I'm doing the spacing for RecyclerView items. It's designed to work with both grids and lists.  The spacing works.

What I can't figure out is how to insert a divider line as well. Any help doing so would be greatly appreciated.

**SIDE NOTE:** if you have a better way to implement the spacing than what I'm currently doing, I'd be very grateful as well :)

```
public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int numOfColumns;
    private int listSize;
    private int offsetInDp;
    private boolean isGridView;
    private boolean canScrollHorizontally;
    private boolean isBottomRow = false;


    public ItemOffsetDecoration(RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager, int listSize, int offsetInDp) {
        this(manager, 1, listSize, offsetInDp);
    }

    public ItemOffsetDecoration(RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager, int numOfColumns, int listSize, int offsetInDp) {
        this.numOfColumns = numOfColumns;
        this.listSize = listSize;
        this.offsetInDp = PixelConversionUtils.dpToPx(offsetInDp);

        this.isGridView = manager instanceof GridLayoutManager;
        this.canScrollHorizontally = manager.canScrollHorizontally();
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                               RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        // only do left/right spacing if grid or horizontal list
        if (isGridView || canScrollHorizontally) {
            outRect.left = offsetInDp;
            outRect.right = offsetInDp;
        }

        // only do top/bottom spacing if grid or vertical list
        if (isGridView || !canScrollHorizontally) {
            int pos = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            boolean isNotTopRow = pos >= numOfColumns;

            // Don't add top spacing to top row
            if (isNotTopRow) {
                outRect.top = offsetInDp;
            }

            int columnIndex = ((GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).getSpanIndex();

            if (pos >= (listSize - numOfColumns) && columnIndex == 0) {
                isBottomRow = true;
            }

            // Don't add bottom spacing to bottom row
            if (!isBottomRow && pos < (listSize - numOfColumns)) {
                outRect.bottom = offsetInDp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here's a quick visual of what I'm looking to do:

here's what I have:

[image]

here's what I want:

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of what you're expecting to get? Is it not enough just having couple: RecyclerView & CardView ?

Comment: done.  take a look

Comment: override `onDraw` / `onDrawOver` then

Comment: @pskink I'm new to itemDecorations.  Could you point me anywhere to assist with that?

Comment: did you try to override those methods? what problems did you face?

Comment: your comment is the first I've seen about onDraw.  Looking into that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve desired look this way:

- first, create a divider Drawable, for this example I've used a simple shape, but you could use default line divider or any other drawable:

  ```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <size android:height="2dp" />
      <size android:width="2dp" />
      <solid android:color="#000000" />
  </shape>
  ```
- second, in your `ItemOffsetDecoration` declare Drawable and initialize it:

  ```
  public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

      private Drawable mDivider;

      ...

      public ItemOffsetDecoration(...) {
          mDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.item_divider);
      }
  }
  ```
- third, override onDrawOver() method:

  ```
  public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
      if (isGridView) {
          drawVerticalDivider(c, parent);
      } else {
          drawVerticalDivider(c, parent);
          drawHorizontalDivider(c, parent);
      }

  }
  ```

  where `drawVerticalDivider()` & `drawHorizontalDivider()` are (might be a good idea to refactor them into the single method and control direction of the divider via parameter):

  ```
  public void drawVerticalDivider(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
      if (parent.getChildCount() == 0) return;

      final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

      for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
          View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
          RecyclerView.LayoutParams params =
                  (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

          int left = child.getLeft() - params.leftMargin - offsetInDp;
          int right = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin + offsetInDp;
          int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin + offsetInDp;
          int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
          mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
          mDivider.draw(c);
      }
  }

  public void drawHorizontalDivider(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
      final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

      for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
          View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
          RecyclerView.LayoutParams params =
                  (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

          int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin + offsetInDp;
          int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth();
          int top = child.getTop() - params.topMargin - offsetInDp;
          int bottom = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin + offsetInDp;
          mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
          mDivider.draw(c);
      }
  }
  ```

Result for the Linear and Grid LayoutManagers:

[image: LinearLayoutManager]         [image: GridLayoutManager]

Comment: this worked wonderfully.  Question:  how would I set the thickness of the dividers?

Comment: also... found a tiny issue that my boss will jump on.  at each intersection, there is no divider drawn.  here's a screen shot that is really small, so I hope it shows... http://imgur.com/c3ehjmp

Comment: @WizardKnight if you used shape from my example, then you need to edit  `size` tag of the Drawable from `2dp` to the desired value. What about the second issue, it might occure because of your way to calculate the value of the `offsetInDp` variable, I used predefined value to set offsets for this example and I don't have such blank dot.

Comment: it has that missing pixel without the offset as well

Comment: @WizardKnight Try to play with `left` variable in the `drawVerticalDivider()` method and `top` variable in the `drawVerticalDivider()` method. Subtract some value from both this variables, like `int top = child.getTop() - params.topMargin - offsetInDp - 5;`. It's pretty dirty approach, but might work.

Answer (score 0):

haha……actualy,i had try like this for Divider ,although with a bit funny : first make you recycleview backgroud with Deep color,and make item_view backgroud white,then marginbottom for every item -> I'm serious, do not vote down :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the following XML snippet to get a divider:

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
      android:background="123e4152"/>
```

You can put this in the recyclerView's item layout beneath your items. Also Play around with the margins and background to suit your list.